# telephony + exchange 2010 (unified messaging)

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2010, telephony

ok i am a complete n00b when it comes to telephony ...
i was wondering we are beginning to play with exchange 2010 in the office ...
How can i connect a telephone line into the server? so we can ring in and get our emails via phone (we have a spare direct line)
I'm going to guess it's not as easy as sticking a 56k modem into the server?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't just plug a modem in. Exchange UM is designed to handle calls passed to it my your telephone system. To setup unified messaging you are going to need PBX server and SIP gateway setup on your telephone network.

[This article](http://blog.lithiumblue.com/2007/04/accessing-exchange-2007-unified_29.html) provides a good introduction to Exchange UM, along with a walk through of how to set it up using open source tools, such as asterix PBX.

Working with telephone systems can be quite complicated, so I suggest you read up and practice as much as you can.

Comment: yep that's the idea... want to know as much as possible before obviously going live 
cheers